# stacktrace.log file is too large

Tags: grails

Inside the target directory of my project, there is a file called stacktrace.log. I have realised size of the file has become more than 3 gigabytes. Is it safe for me to delete this file? Would it cause any file not found exceptions after deleting it? Thanks for your time.

---edit

If it does cause file not found exception, how can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 9):

`stacktrace.log` is the default location where Grails writes the unfiltered stack traces of exceptions thrown by the app (for normal logging it filters out stack frames that are "internal" groovy mechanics, but sometimes it can be too aggressive so it's handy to have the full traces available). You can safely delete it and it will get recreated empty next time the app starts.

You can control this in [the `log4j` DSL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging) in `Config.groovy`, under the `appenders` block. The default behaviour is equivalent to an appender definition of

```
file name:'stacktrace', file:'stacktrace.log`
```

in prod mode and `file:'target/stacktrace.log'` in dev mode, you could replace it with e.g.

```
rollingFile name:'stacktrace', file:'stacktrace.log',
    maxFileSize:'5MB', maxBackupIndex:2
```

to limit it to 15MB (the active file plus up to two rolled-over backups).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is just an log file,If you delete it,the later log will be missing.altough it depends on what logging framwork you are using.

Suggest you to use [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) to rolling the log.It can avoid the log to be to Fat.