# What to do about huge stacktrace.log file in grails

Tags: grails

The project I'm working on has a stacktrace.log file that is over 160GB in space. This is killing my hardrive space. What can I do to avoid this.

Comment: Did some searching. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15848829/1264846

Answer (score 3):

You should use rolling file appender so that the log file does not grow that huge size.
Use configuration like:

```
rollingFile name:'stacktrace', file:'stacktrace.log',
maxFileSize:'100MB', maxBackupIndex:5
```

Here every log file will be maximum 100 MB. You can control how many previous file will be existed by 'maxBackupIndex'.

You can empty the existing huge file by(in linux)

```
cat /dev/null > /path/to/file/stacktrace.log
```